How to implement _mm256_sign_epi8 in ARM NEON?
Is there a convenient way to implement x86's _mm256_sign_epi8 (vpsignb) in NEON?
I want to use 1 bit to decide whether negate or non-negate a int8x16_t vector in NEON. It is easy when coding with AVX by using _mm256_sign_epi8. However, I did not find a instruction in neon which functions exactly like _mm256_sign_epi8, how can I implement it in NEON without multiply?

psignb isn't just a conditional-negate, it also zeros if the second source operand is zero which is neither positive nor negative. (I added a link to Intel's manual to your question.)  If you don't care about that behaviour, negate into a temporary and blend would be one way.  Or the 2's complement bithack like used for absolute-value without cmov: arithmetic right-shift to get 0 or -1, and ADD + XOR with it.  ARM has 8-bit SIMD shifts, unlike x86.

Also note that NEON is a 128-bit vector ISA.  _mm256_sign_epi8 is the 256-bit version of _mm_sign_epi8.  If you want 256-bit vector ops on ARM, you need SVE.  (Or you need to emulate it as two halves, I guess, but then it's the same problem as emulating _mm_sign_epi8.)

Semi-related: Is there an function in AVX512 like _mm512_sign_epi16 (__m512i a, __m512i b) is about emulating an AVX-512 version of it.  (There are no AVX-512 versions of vpsignb/w/d.)  If you're using SVE, a similar test / masked-subtract (from zero) could work.

If you only want conditionally negate but not zero out these bytes, use the following C++ function.
inline int8x16_t sign_epi8_nz_sat( int8x16_t v, int8x16_t mask )
{
    // mask = ( mask < 0 ) ? 0xFF : 0
    mask = vcltzq_s8( mask );

    // Negate integers in the input vector
    // Note we use saturating version, will transform -128 into +127
    const int8x16_t neg = vqnegq_s8( v );
    // Conditionally negate the numbers based on the mask
    return vbslq_s8( mask, neg, v );
}

If you want a complete equivalent of _mm_sign_epi8 you need more NEON instructions, use the following version.
inline int8x16_t sign_epi8( int8x16_t v, int8x16_t mask )
{
    // negMask = ( mask < 0 ) ? 0xFF : 0
    const int8x16_t negMask = vcltzq_s8( mask );
    // zeroMask = ( 0 == mask ) ? 0xFF : 0
    const int8x16_t zeroMask = vceqzq_s8( mask );

    // Conditionally negate the numbers based on the negMask, without saturation
    const int8x16_t neg = vnegq_s8( v );
    v = vbslq_s8( negMask, neg, v );
    // Zero out numbers where mask byte was exactly zero
    return vbicq_s8( v, zeroMask );
}

The code is untested.

Why vtst instead of an arithmetic right shift?  A shift wouldn't need a vector constant.  Is it less efficient?

@njuffa Good idea, I’ve updated the answer accordingly.

@PeterCordes See the update, it seems Arm64 NEON has a special instruction to compare signed integers for e < 0 without using a constant vector

Oh cool, nice.  The OP asked for NEON, which means technically implies 32-bit mode.  (AArch64 128-bit SIMD is officially called ASIMD, Advanced SIMD.)  But a lot of people just say NEON even when talking about AArch64.

@PeterCordes It seems people who write documentation for developer.arm.com also say Neon when talking about ARM32 and ARM64 SIMD; see checkboxes on the left of that page https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets/intrinsics/
